# When a striped candy destroys a row, is the row direction random?

Tags: candy-crush-saga

When you combine 4 candies in a row, you are left with a striped version of that candy. If you subsequently destroy that striped candy, it will destroy a whole row of candies.

I have noticed that the row direction is sometimes horizontal, and sometimes vertical.

Is this chosen by random? or is there specific logic that determines the direction? If so, what is that logic?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

1. When you *use* a striped candy, you can tell which direction it will clear based on the direction of the stripes:

   [image]
2. The *direction* of the stripes is determined by the direction you moved the final candy to *create* the striped candy, as described below.

According to my experience and [online sources](http://flickrshare.blogspot.ca/2013/01/top-10-candy-crush-saga-tips-hints.html):

The direction of row/column destroying candy (indicated by the direction of the stripes on the candy) is determined by the direction you moved the piece to create the special candy.

```
--X-                   --X-
--X                    --X-
-X-- Move horizontally --X- creates a row destroyer that destroys horizontally
--X-                   --X-

----                 ----
-X--                 ----
X-XX Move vertically XXXX creates a column destroyer that destroys vertically
----                 ----
```

Moreover the location of special pieces is the location of where the piece that was moved to create the bonus ended up. So:

In the first example, it doesn't really matter because the special candy will fall to the bottom.

In the second example, the bonus would appear at the location second from the left like so:

```
----
----
-O--  
----
```

In the event that you move a striped candy to create another striped candy, the location of the new striped candy will be randomly selected from one of the other candies in the set and the striped candy you just moved will activate.

Comment: Although not as concise as the extract I found from one of the links in the other answer. It does explain it well, and for the extra effort I will award you by accepting this answer. It would be nice if you could edit in something about the direction of the stripes indicating which direction it will destroy

Comment: @mousefan I appreciate that. I put the bit about the stripe directions in. Technically, both answers are fairly close in length after the inclusion of your extract - mine takes much more space because I ASCII'd up a visual representation to make a clear demonstration of what was happening in case the wording wasn't getting the point across. I like David Toh's links better than mine, but the information is essentially the same.

Comment: In my experience, one caveat is that, if the piece you move into position to make four-in-a-row is already a striped candy, then a different piece in the group will become a new striped candy.

Comment: Good point @AdamV . I've added that to the answer. It's been several months since I last played, but that reminds me that I recall seeing striped candy match made entirely out of striped candy due to cascades, but I can't recall where the new striped candy, if any, ended up. I can't find an answer in my recent searches. I'll look into it more when I have the opportunity and update the answer further.

Answer (score 3):

Check out these websites for more information on how the candies work

http://candy-crush-saga.wikia.com/wiki/Candies

Or, check out this one which has a better explanation.

http://www.imore.com/candy-crush-top-10-tips-tricks-and-cheats and got to the 4th tip.

Taken from the second link:

> Candy is stripped in the same direction as the final candy moved to
>   complete the previous formation. If your move a candy horizontally, it
>   will make a horizontal stripe, which will then explode horizontally as
>   well.

Comment: @musefan Too bad I can only approve but not upvote your edit - turning a rather tiny link-only answer into something probably helpful - #DavidToh, please try to be more verbose here, it's always annoying to see an answer only consisting of links that may become dead at one point in the future, therefore it's strongly recommended to provde at least a relevant excerpt of that information

Comment: David, I chose not to accept this answer based on the fact it was just a couple of links originally. If you had included the extract that I edited in, I would have accepted it. Just something to keep in mind for your next answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on how you are combining candies in the game. If you are combining four candies in a column or vertical way, you are creating vertical striped candy, which will clear the entire column candies. If you are combining four candies in a row or horizontal way, you are creating horizontal striped candy, which will clear the entire row candies.
For more information Visit: [How to create Striped Candies](http://candycrushsagagamecheats.com/special-candies-list/)

Comment: Actually, are you sure this is correct? It all depends on which direction you move the last piece, doesn't matter which direction the 'row of four' is facing