# Is the row direction random when the striped candy is created indirectly?

Tags: candy-crush-saga

When the striped candy is created due to other candy is cleared (unlike we create the striped candy [directly](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/124886/27425)), is the row direction random or is there any logic behind it's direction?

E.g.

```
---##---
---00##-
--0-----
```

In the above situation if I clear the candy "0" it will create a striped candy for "#" (because candies `#` will go down by one row.) like below:

```
--------
---####-
--------

Will result in

--------
-----*--
--------
```

But I am not sure the direction of this striped candy which is created indirectly. Is it created by any logic or is it created randomly?

Note: I am not asking the location of the striped candy. It is random AFAIK.

---

Footnotes:

- `0`: red candy
- `#`: blue candy
- `*`:  *striped* blue candy

Comment: I am at max level allowed on android and can confirm that when stripes created indirectly, the result is completely random. I have seen both ways and no pattern when created indirectly.

Comment: @Huangism: Yeah. Now I too can confirm as I am at Level 760. :)

Comment: The levels only get more annoying as you go, becomes a game of pure luck

Comment: @Huangism: I have started to hate it but still I want to complete all remaining levels. :)

Comment: Good luck and I mean it because without luck this game becomes impossible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As for all the special candy i never seen a patern in the position nor the direction of the stripes when creating these indirectly. This seems (is) completely random. Source: I'm currently at level 165.

Comment: I agree.  I've both never seen a pattern myself, nor have I read about one on various sites where folks are asking this same question.  If there is causality to it, it must be extremely hard to predict.

Answer (score 0):

if the row is horizontal, the striped candy will be vertical.  if vertical, the candy will be created to clear a horizontal row.

Comment: I believe that only applies when you create the row yourself. If they are created as described in the question I don't think they hold to the same rules. It has been a while since I last played and this question is quite old so if you think this has been updated (or that the existing answer is incorrect) then you might want to put more information on when you think it changed.